# Limit zoom to designated images

Tags: javascript, image, zooming

The following js code works fine. The problem is it's zooming ALL "img" tags on the page. I only need it to zoom certain images. I tried created a class called "zoom" for the img tag and made appropriate changes to the code but it's not working. If you know how to modify the code to do so, please let me know. Thanks!

```
$('body').append('<div class="product-image-overlay"><span class="product-image-overlay-close">x</span><img src="" /></div>');
var productImage = $('img');
var productOverlay = $('.product-image-overlay');
var productOverlayImage = $('.product-image-overlay img');
productImage.click(function () {
var productImageSource = $(this).attr('src');

productOverlayImage.attr('src', productImageSource);
productOverlay.fadeIn(100);
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');

$('.product-image-overlay-close').click(function () {
    productOverlay.fadeOut(100);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
});
```

Comment: I don't see any code related to img zoom in your script? I am not getting what exactly you want. Can you elaborate in more detail please.

Comment: The code all img tags on the page and zooms them when you click on the image. I'm trying to modify it so that it limits the images it zooms to exclude non-picture related images that have img tags.